# Google Sheets : Detect how to tag a row of data based on a delimited range of tags

Tags: google-sheets, search, tags, match, vlookup

I am getting crazy concerning the best way to realize the following :

I get from my bank a CSV containing all my banking transactions of the month.

I have a set of tags that I have predefined.

I would like to automatically tag a row of data with specific tags

Example : "01/01/2024 Harris Teeter $55" => Tagged Food

I created a table that lists the mapping of each company from which I bought, and how I want them to be associated with tags

[image: TAB1]

TAB1 : BANK DATA
COL A :
01/01/2024 Harris Teeter $55
01/01/2024 3X 4X ONEY $200
01/01/2024 PAIEMENT CARTE DU 29/12 15:30 AMAZON PAYMENTS $7,99
01/01/2024 Google Payment IE LTD Goo $9,99

01/01/2024 Total $20
Etc..

[image: TAB2 : Tags]

TAB 2 : TAGS
COL A                COL B
Harris Teeter | Food
Amazon        | Movies
Google        | IT
Total         | Car expenses
Oney          | Decathlon
Etc

END RESULT EXPECTED :

[image: End result expected]

TAB1 : BANK DATA

COL A :
01/01/2024 Harris Teeter $55                                      | FOOD
01/01/2024 3X 4X ONEY $200                                        | DECATHLON
01/01/2024 PAIEMENT CARTE DU 29/12 15:30 AMAZON PAYMENTS $7,99    | MOVIES
01/01/2024 Google Payment IE LTD Goo $9,99                        | IT
01/01/2024 Total $20                                              | CAR EXPENSES

I have tried the whole day to use QUERY, LOOKUP, VLOOKUP, SEARCH, INDEX, MATCH but I haven't been able to find a simple way to search if a tag is present in the bank data.

Would you have a clue on how to implement this ?

Thanks a lot,

Emma

I tried so many things..

What I succeded best was to do this :
=STXT(bank_row;SEARCH(TAGS;bank_row);length)

But I'm using the SEARCH function in a wrong way. With this, I am able to find values of TAB 1 that match in TAB 2. Whereas I want to match values of TAB2 in TAB1

With the above formula, I handle to do this :

TAB 2 : TAG
COL A                COL B
Harris Teeter | Food           | 01/01/2024 Harris Teeter $55
Amazon        | Movies         |
Google        | IT             |
Total         | Car expenses   |
Oney          | Decathlon      |

This is not what I want because I want to have the tag associated in tab 1 with my bank data. Not vice verca.

So many thanks if someone comes up with an idea.

Comment: can you share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result?

Answer (score 0):

*Here's a generalized approach you can test out (`adjust the formula as per your sheet ranges`):*

```js
=map(A:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+torow(byrow(filter(E:F,E:E<>""),lambda(Λ,if(search(index(Λ,,1),Σ),index(Λ,,2),))),3),"-"))))
```

[image]

***DISCLAIMER***: *If a transaction has more than one tag matches, lets say `google` & `total` then only first match from the tag list `Google→IT` will be thrown as output (`Total→Car expenses` will be ignored)*

Comment: woaw thank you so much @rockinfreakshow ! Sorry for my late reply, I only noticed the answer now. Quick question : what does the + sign in front of torow mean ?

Otherwise, I managed to make it work, just replacing commas by semi colons in google spreadsheet.

Comment: Its just a shortcut to limit an array value to single cell value; more of like `index(<range>,1,1)`

Comment: I'm guessing that this is this precise + sign that generates the limitation of the analysis in tags to only the first result that matches ?

Anyway, it's awesome, works great.  Thank you SO MUCH !

Comment: Its time-taking to create formulas *if data is provided via screenshots OR unformatted style* since we've to manually arrange the test data & then create formulas as well! For future `1` You can easily share test data via this [table generator](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table). Just paste the *data rows/columns* in this generator→press enter→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table. `2` You can also share a test sheet using this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)